# How can I prevent yellow and dead grass?

Tags: lawn, grass, fertilizer, lawn-repair

Every year I spread grass seed in the yard. However a part of the lawn still became yellow and even died.

A few weeks ago I put on Scott Turf Builder Southern Gold Grass Seed. It still died.

[image: 1]

I am despaired. I guess that I lack knowledge in this area. What I should do now?

Comment: Hi Love. This sounds so frustrating! Is this the same lawn as in any of your other questions? If so, which one? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue, yes it is the same lawn. I just spread the seed. The seed is just "float" on the soil.

Comment: Did you lay the lawn in the first place? I was wondering what is underneath this patch that may be different to the rest.

Comment: @Rosie, it is not a new house. I moved into it in 2008. It was beautiful at that time. I am not strong on managing the lawn.

Comment: Don't worry, you can't do everything perfectly. That's probably good news, it should be the easiest remedy then as Jim has suggested, aerate the soil and if you can, sweep sand into the holes. Scarify the top to remove the thatch and reseed. You may need to keep the birds off to prevent them eating your seed.  If this is used regularly as a crossover path/shortcut, make it a path and be done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have developed a 'hard pan': the soil has become compacted and won't absorb water well.

Applying gypsum or garden lime to the area may help. It might also help to poke around to loosen the soil in those areas (like stab it repeatedly with a garden fork or a lawn aerator).

Comment: Do I have to plug it? Because I received an coupon about it. A landscape company threw it to my lawn. I think that there is a reason for that.

Comment: Well, if I had a landscape company, I would see you as an opportunity to make some money (not that there is anything wrong with that). I think you have a serious soil issue. Plugging is simply poking a piece of sod in a shallow hole. You then wait for the grass to spread from the array of plugs. I don't see that to be necessary, nor do I think it remedies your underlying problem.  I've offered you free advice, but I no guarantee. If the landscaper, on the other hand, gives you a guarantee, it could be worthwhile for you, coupon or not.

Comment: How much did you water the seed? It would need regular watering so especially if the seeds were just sown.  Seedlings are very fragile and would be easy to fry in hot sun for example. It wouldn't have been sufficient to water them in and then just leave. They would probably have needed daily watering in the early morning or in the evening, if hot both times.

Comment: @Rosie, a follow up question. I bought [patch master](http://www.scotts.com/smg/goprod/patchmaster-sun-shade-mix/prod70132). I am not sure should I still seeding the lawn?

Comment: It depends on the season where you are.  I would think that if it was spring or Autumn, or if you are to have a period of warm but not hot/dry weather give it a go.